# Implementing Subprograms-Active record instance stack depict

Tags: activerecord, subprocess, programming-languages

The original question is:
Show the stack with all activation record instances, including static and dynamic chains, when execution reaches position 1 in the following skeletal program. Assume Bigsub is at level 1.

[image]

And the answer is:
[image]

But I think the answer is wrong, because the **static** link should point to the bottom of it static parent's ARI, not the top, just the dynamic link should point to the top.

For example, the static link of B and C should point to the bottom of A, not the top of A, and the static link of A should point to the bottom of BIGSUB, isn't it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The layout of activation records depends on the implementation. Looking at the pseudocode for using the records should let you know if the example is correct. Which is the *top*/*bottom* of a record depends on the implementation (I'll use *top* as you did in what follows, although it is *bottom* to me).

In the example, pointing to the other end ("top") of a record is unnecessary because those addresses are always at `STACK[DYNAMIC_LINK_ADDRESS]+1`.
V
The routines in the example don't define parameters or local variables, and that makes it harder to imagine how the activation records would be used.

If each routine defined `X` and `Y` variables, then the stack might look like the following pseudo-table, with both the dynamic and static links pointing to where parameters and variables can be found in the stack by using positive offsets (with the same offsets being used when variables are local or non-local; `A.X` is at `+02` on activation records for A).

```
N-17: DL -> 12
N-16: SL -> 07
N-15: B.X
N-14: B.Y
N-13: RET C
N-12: DL -> 07
N-11: SL -> 07
N-10: C.X
N-09: C.Y
N-08: RET A
N-07: DL -> 02
N-06: SL -> 02
N-05: A.X
N-04: A.Y
N-03: RET BITSUB
N-02: BIGSUB.X
N-01: BIGSUB.Y
```